# UITabBarControllerDelegate action not called

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

It looks like a lot of new iOS developers have problems with this objective c class.
I'm trying to detect which of the 5 tab items is tapped (home, products, my cart, search, more). 
Based on the index tapped (0, 2, 4), I want to display the root view, if there are any other views stacked on top of it.
Here's AppDelegate.h code:

```
@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate, UITabBarControllerDelegate> {
    UITabBarController *tabBarController;
}

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UITabBarController *tabBarController;
@end
```

AppDelegate.h code :

```
@synthesize tabBarController;

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    self.tabBarController.delegate = self;
    return YES;
}

- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController{
    NSLog(@"action called.");
}
```

Comment: This may not be enough information to diagnose the issue – what do you mean by "display the root view, if there are any other views stacked on top of it"? Are you using navigation controllers inside your tab bar controller?

Comment: Yes,that's exactly what I'm doing. Each tab bar item has embedded navigation controllers. Sorry, for not being more precise.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this by calling the selected view controller's `-popToRootViewControllerAnimated:` method inside your tab bar controller's delegate method:

```
- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {
    NSUInteger vcIndex = [[tabBarController viewControllers] indexOfObject:viewController];
    BOOL shouldPop = (vcIndex == 0 || vcIndex == 2 || vcIndex == 4);
    if (shouldPop && [viewController isKindOfClass:[UINavigationController class]]) {
        [(UINavigationController *)viewController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    }
}
```

Keep in mind, though, that this may not be the best user experience – users often expect that they can switch between tabs without losing their position or state when returning to another tab. Popping to the root view controller will often throw away that state, which can lead to frustration.

Comment: Thanks Tim, you're onto something, but it still does not get called. I put it it the AppDelegate.h file, but nothing happens.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I misunderstood. Have you hooked up your `tabBarController` property to a UITabBarController instance in a storyboard? What is the value of `self.tabBarController` inside `-application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`?

Comment: No, I haven't. That could be it. How do I hook it up? In the storyboard, TabBarController to an outlet delegate? Xcode won't let me do that.

Comment: Here's the screenshot : http://ivanharmat.com/uploads/ee8390718cae8ff01630b4dac2efbf94.png

Comment: It looks like you want the tab bar controller's delegate to be your app delegate; I don't know of a way to hook up something to the app delegate in a storyboard. If your tab bar controller is the root controller of your window, you might get at it that way instead - what is `self.window.rootViewController` in your app delegate method?